# Make a Body move forward / towards a point with matter.js in Phaser.io

Tags: phaser-framework, matter.js

I am trying to move a Body in [Matter.js](http://brm.io/matter-js/) (or GameObject in [Phaser 3](http://phaser.io)) towards the mouse cursor.

I have calculated the angle and I'd also have a calculated vector towards which the Body should move.

So using `angle`, `toPoint`, `speed` I want to move the Body towards the cursor.

At the simplest I'd just need something like `GameObject.moveForwardConstantly(speed)`.

Unfortunately `GameObject.setVelocity` doesn't move the object in the direction which angle it is pointing to. Neither does `thrust`.

I can't really find anything on how to do this without dragging the item, but just moving the mouse around.